# Counting number of orders per customer

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following columns: `date`, `customers_id`, and `orders_id` (unique).
I want to addd a column in which, for each `order_id`, I can see how many times the given customer has already placed an order during the previous year.
e.g. this is what it would look like:

```
customers_id | orders_id |    date     | order_rank
   2083      |   4725    | 2018-08-314 |     1
   2573      |   4773    | 2018-09-035 |     1
   3393      |   3776    | 2017-09-11  |     1
   3393      |   4172    | 2018-01-09  |     2
   3393      |   4655    | 2018-08-17  |     3
```

I'm doing this in BigQuery, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `count(*)` with a window frame.  Ideally, you would use an interval.  But BigQuery doesn't (yet) support that syntax.  So convert to a number:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customer_id
                      order by unix_date(date)
                      range between 364 preceding and current row
                     ) as order_rank
from t;
```

This treats a year as 365 days, which seems suitable for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the `over` clause and restrict the data in your `where` clause. You don't really need a window for your case. If you consider one your a period from 365 days in the past until now, this is gonna work:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customer_id
                      order by date
                     ) as c
from `your-table` t
where date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)
order by customer_id, c
```

If you need some specific year, for example 2019, you can do something like:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customer_id
                      order by date
                     ) as c
from `your-table` t
where date between cast("2019-01-01" as date) and cast("2019-12-31" as date)
order by customer_id, c
```